# Perl script for ssh login with password and run a command on the remote server

Tags: perl, ssh

I want to check the disk usage of my servers and send a mail if the usage is above 90%.

I have to do it in perl script. I thought to login into every server using ssh (with password as i cannot set up public & private keys for ssh session) and run the following command which would return me the disk usage in root partition :-
**df -h | awk '{ print $5}' | sed 's/capacity//g' | sed 's/%//g' | awk '/./' | awk -F. '{print $1}'| head -1**
But i can't seem to find anyway to login into servers through ssh without having to install any perl modules like Net::OpenSSH or to use /usr/bin/expect.

Is there any plain and simple way to login through ssh and automate the password prompt without using any external perl modules? 
Also after loging in, i want to run that command on all the server and store the output into a variable for comparision. Please advice

Many regards :)

Comment: Why don't you want to install any perl modules?

Comment: because i can't download and install any packages in my working environment :(

Comment: If the issue is just automated logins for SSH, exchange public SSH keys between your servers.

Comment: There is no way to automate SSH password authentication without using `expect` (or its perl/python/etc. module equivalents) or `sshpass` or some SSH client supporting it (for instance `plink`).

Answer (score -1):

install sshpass via apt-get

fire the below command from the perl script

qx(sshpass -p 'root' ssh username\@hostname 'command to execute on a machine');

Note: Replace username and hostname in the above command.