# Find hostname of remote server through ssh in perl

Tags: perl, ssh

I have an array which contains a series of IPs. Now i'm trying to connect to those IPs through ssh and echo their hostname. I came accross [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838158/perl-script-for-ssh-login-with-password-and-run-a-command-on-the-remote-server) but didn't get much info out of it. This is what I've got:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Term::ANSIColor;
print colored( "Number of machines: \n", 'green' );
my $number = <>;

my @arr = ();
my $ip = 0;
while (@arr < $number) {
        print colored( "\nIP Address: \n", 'green' );
        my $IP = <STDIN>;
        chomp $IP;
        push @arr, $IP;
}


print colored( "this is the hostname:\n", 'green' ); foreach $ip (@arr) {
        print "`ssh host\@$ip hostname \n`";
}
```

but I get following error:

```
Can't use string ("IP") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at
```

When I remove `use strict; the error is also removed, but the code still doesn't work`

---

edit:
the \@ did the trick of removing the error but now it just prints

```
`ssh axiroot@172.31.222.135` `hostname`
```

while it should print just the hostname

Comment: Removing the [safety net](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Safety-net) doesn't prevent the fall!

Comment: If i wanted to have the code working without use strict, then I would've deleted it from my code ofcourse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax

```
@$ip
```

In your print statement is interpreted as an array reference. That is what caused the error.

Try escaping:

```
"...host\@$ip..."
```

Furthermore, you can use backticks to execute a command and capture the output

```
`ssh bla@example.com hostname`
```

But you have surrounded the backticks with quotes, rendering them useless.. I think you want to remove the quotes.

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick for the error but not for the command, I have edited the question

Answer (score 2):

`@$ip` in the print statement is your problem. Try changing to `\@$ip`.

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick for the error but not for the command, I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Your print has too many quotes to execute the ssh command.  Try

```
 print `ssh host\@$ip hostname \n`;
```

or

```
system "ssh host\@$ip hostname \n";
```

Finally, "host" must be a valid user on the remote machine.  The syntax for ssh is

```
ssh user@remote-host
```